# How can I create an Emacs keyboard macro to make Clojure code easier for humans to read it?

Tags: align

I am working on a Clojure codebase. Sometimes, we have code as:

```clj
:boxes [{:id "Do-not-map"                        :description "Do Not Map, expenses"             :line "0"  :cch-box-number "0"  :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true}}
                        {:id "Unconverted"                       :description "Unconverted"                      :line "0"  :cch-box-number "0"  :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                        {:id "Personal"                          :description "Personal"                         :line "0"  :cch-box-number "0"  :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                        {:id "Do-not-map-income"                 :description "Do Not Map, income"               :line "0"  :cch-box-number "0"  :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Revenue"}}
                        {:id "Do-not-map-assets"                 :description "Do Not Map, assets"               :line "0"  :cch-box-number "0"  :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "debit-norm" :tax-account-type "Assets"}}
                        {:id "Do-not-map-liabilities"            :description "Do Not Map, liabilities"          :line "0"  :cch-box-number "0"  :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Liabilities"}}
                        {:id "Do-not-map-equity"                 :description "Do Not Map, equity"               :line "0"  :cch-box-number "0"  :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Equity"}}]
```

The structured whitespace between keywords (words starting with `:`) is **probably not** an idiomatic style of Clojure code. I believe [a famous style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide) used by the community does not cover this. But, note that it looks nice in the text editor for human readability:

[image]

The code above was manually tweaked to be like that. The default code, on the other hand, is as follows (note the absence of structured whitespace on the image):

```clj
:boxes [{:id "SchE-4-Royalties-received"  :line  "4"  :description "Royalties received"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Royalties received"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",110, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "504"  :ultratax-description "Royalty income"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L4"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["Royalty income"]  :contra-flip true}}
                        {:id "SchE-5-Advertising"  :line  "5"  :description "Advertising"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Advertising"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",4, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "505"  :ultratax-description "Advertising"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L5"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["ads" "advertising" "google" "ad words" "facebook" "posting" "craigslist" "classifieds" "seo" "search"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-6-Auto-and-travel"  :line  "6"  :description "Auto and travel"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Auto and travel"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",5, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "506"  :ultratax-description "Auto and travel"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L6"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["Auto" "car" "gas" "truck" "travel"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-7-Cleaning-and-maintenance"  :line  "7"  :description "Cleaning and maintenance"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Cleaning and maintenance"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",6, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "507"  :ultratax-description "Cleaning and maintenance"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L7"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["cleaning" "maintenance"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-8-Commissions"  :line  "8"  :description "Commissions"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Commissions"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",7, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "508"  :ultratax-description "Commissions"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L8"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["commission"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-9-Insurance-(does-not-include-PMI)"  :line  "9"  :description "Insurance"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Insurance"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",8, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "509"  :ultratax-description "Insurance"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L9"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["insurance"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-10-Legal-and-other-professional-fees"  :line  "10"  :description "Legal and other professional fees"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Legal and professional fees"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",10, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "510"  :ultratax-description "Legal and other prof fees"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L10"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["legal" "accounting" "bookkeeping" "consulting"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-11-Management-fees-(rental-agencies-and-property-management-companies)"  :line  "11"  :description "Management fees"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Management fees"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",19, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "511"  :ultratax-description "Management fees"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L11"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["management"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-12-Mortgage-interest-paid-to-banks"  :line  "12"  :description "Mortgage interest paid to banks, etc."  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Mortgage interest expense"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",9, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "512"  :ultratax-description "Mortgage interest"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L12"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["mortgage"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-13-Other-interest"  :line  "13"  :description "Other interest"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Other interest expense"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",29, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "513"  :ultratax-description "Other interest"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L13"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["interest"  "private loan interest" "private"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-14-Repairs"  :line  "14"  :description "Repairs"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Repairs"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",11, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "514"  :ultratax-description "Repairs"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L14"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["repairs" "plumbing"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-15-Suppliers"  :line  "15"  :description "Suppliers"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Supplies"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",12, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "515"  :ultratax-description "Supplies"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L15"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["supplies" "Supply"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-16-Taxes"  :line  "16"  :description "Taxes"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Taxes"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",13, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "516"  :ultratax-description "Taxes"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L16"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["taxes" "tax" "property tax"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-17-Utilities"  :line  "17"  :description "Utilities"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Utilities"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",14, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "517"  :ultratax-description "Utilities"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L17"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["utilities" "water" "gas" "garbage" "recology"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-18-Depreciation-expense-or-depletion"  :line  "18"  :description "Depreciation expense or depletion"  :qbd-name ""  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",30, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "520"  :ultratax-description "Depreciation"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L18"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["depreciation"]}}
                        {:id "SchE-19-Other"  :line  "19"  :description "Other"  :qbd-name "Schedule E: Other expenses"  :qbd-scd ""  :drake-qbd-tax-name ""  :drake-name ""  :cch-line-description ""  :import-tax-code ""  :lacerte-coord ["53","0",27, {:rental-property-ordinal-to-prefix true}]  :ultratax-coord "518"  :ultratax-description "Other expenses"  :ultratax-form-line "Sch E, L19"  :cch-box-number ""  :tags {:fuzzy-regexs ["other:" "other expense" "misc" "miscellaneous" "bank" "education" "professional" "development" "postage" "shipping" "travel" "meals"]}}]
```

On Emacs (and other text editors) it looks as:

[image]

I would like to adjust the latter code to be formatted like the former. Instead of doing it in a manual manner, I would like to use Emacs power to do the trick. This feels like a good call for macros. But, I do not know how to use keyboard macros on Emacs.

How to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Please don't ask whether something is the "best way" to accomplish something. That encourages opinion-based answers - it's something to ask at a discussion site perhaps, such as Reddit.

Comment: It might help if you reduced your example to a minimum for what you want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacemacs has a function named `spacemacs/align-repeat` that can almost do what you want.  The way it works is that you highlight a region and then run this function on it interactively.  It will ask for a regexp pattern to align the text on, and in your case, you'd use `:\w+`.  It's mapped to <kbd>SPC x a r</kbd> in Spacemacs, but you can say <kbd>M-x spacemacs/align-repeat</kbd> if you want.

Looking at the function, there isn't anything specific to Spacemacs in it, so I'm going to post it here.

```lisp
(defun spacemacs/align-repeat (start end regexp &optional justify-right after)
  "Repeat alignment with respect to the given regular expression.
If JUSTIFY-RIGHT is non nil justify to the right instead of the
left. If AFTER is non-nil, add whitespace to the left instead of
the right."
  (interactive "r\nsAlign regexp: ")
  (let* ((ws-regexp (if (string-empty-p regexp)
                        "\\(\\s-+\\)"
                      "\\(\\s-*\\)"))
         (complete-regexp (if after
                              (concat regexp ws-regexp)
                            (concat ws-regexp regexp)))
         (group (if justify-right -1 1)))

    (unless (use-region-p)
      (save-excursion
        (while (and
                (string-match-p complete-regexp (thing-at-point 'line))
                (= 0 (forward-line -1)))
          (setq start (point-at-bol))))
      (save-excursion
        (while (and
                (string-match-p complete-regexp (thing-at-point 'line))
                (= 0 (forward-line 1)))
          (setq end (point-at-eol)))))

    (align-regexp start end complete-regexp group 1 t)))
```

If you dig through the [source](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/develop/layers/+spacemacs/spacemacs-defaults/funcs.el#L1281), you'll see that it's a refinement of the code found on the [AlignCommands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands) page on EmacsWiki.

### Test Run

I'm going to start with this initial state.

```clj
[{:id "Do-not-map" :description "Do Not Map, expenses" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true}}
 {:id "Unconverted" :description "Unconverted" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 {:id "Personal" :description "Personal" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 {:id "Do-not-map-income" :description "Do Not Map, income" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Revenue"}}
 {:id "Do-not-map-assets" :description "Do Not Map, assets" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "debit-norm" :tax-account-type "Assets"}}
 {:id "Do-not-map-liabilities" :description "Do Not Map, liabilities" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Liabilities"}}
 {:id "Do-not-map-equity" :description "Do Not Map, equity" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Equity"}}]
```

Then I'm going to run `spacemacs/align-repeat` on it using `:\w+` as my repeat pattern which yields the following.

```clj
[{ :id "Do-not-map"             :description "Do Not Map, expenses"    :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting { :omit-taxable true} :tags { :do-not-map true}}
 { :id "Unconverted"            :description "Unconverted"             :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting { :omit-taxable true} :tags { :do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 { :id "Personal"               :description "Personal"                :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting { :omit-taxable true} :tags { :do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 { :id "Do-not-map-income"      :description "Do Not Map, income"      :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting { :omit-taxable true} :tags { :do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Revenue"}}
 { :id "Do-not-map-assets"      :description "Do Not Map, assets"      :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting { :omit-taxable true} :tags { :do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "debit-norm"  :tax-account-type "Assets"}}
 { :id "Do-not-map-liabilities" :description "Do Not Map, liabilities" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting { :omit-taxable true} :tags { :do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Liabilities"}}
 { :id "Do-not-map-equity"      :description "Do Not Map, equity"      :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting { :omit-taxable true} :tags { :do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Equity"}}]
```

It added some spaces after the `{` and before the `:`, so I'll apply the regexp replacement `s/{ :/{:/g` on the same region to tighten it up.  (I'm an evil user.)

```clj
[{:id "Do-not-map"             :description "Do Not Map, expenses"    :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true}}
 {:id "Unconverted"            :description "Unconverted"             :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 {:id "Personal"               :description "Personal"                :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :suppress-ui true}} ;¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 {:id "Do-not-map-income"      :description "Do Not Map, income"      :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Revenue"}}
 {:id "Do-not-map-assets"      :description "Do Not Map, assets"      :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "debit-norm"  :tax-account-type "Assets"}}
 {:id "Do-not-map-liabilities" :description "Do Not Map, liabilities" :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Liabilities"}}
 {:id "Do-not-map-equity"      :description "Do Not Map, equity"      :line "0" :cch-box-number "0" :import-tax-code "0" :reporting {:omit-taxable true} :tags {:do-not-map true :tax-norm-bal "credit-norm" :tax-account-type "Equity"}}]
```

PS:  Perl programmers (known for their penchant for [ASCII art](https://ascii.co.uk/art/perl)) like to do this kind of thing.  Their code formatter, [perltidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltidy#Controlling-Vertical-Alignment), does this by default.

Comment: It worked out as expected. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Enjoy writing beautiful code.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this in a more editor-agnostic way is to use [zprint](https://github.com/kkinnear/zprint). It's a clojure formatter that's kind of crazy configurable, and there is a way to have it [justify code](https://github.com/kkinnear/zprint/blob/main/doc/reference.md#justified).

From emacs, you can interactively run zprint on a buffer or region using the [zprint-format](https://github.com/dpassen/zprint-format) package.

A benefit here is that many developers can share the same zprint config, even if they don't all use the same editor.